# OS X El Capitan & Android Studio 1.4

Tags: macos, launchd, path, android

Has anyone else noticed the following with Android Studio 1.4 running on OS X El Capitan?

I can't remember the exact point when I lost the ability to build an Android app from the IDE due to the fact that the extensive set of custom pre build steps that I have failed to run. Those custom steps run a Python-script, and the main problem is that gradle doesn't seem to find the Python-binary due to the fact that the PATH environment variable is the extremely sparse list of `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

Here are some random points related to finding this issue:

- This problem does not affect building from the terminal.
- This problem is specific to OS X, none of my Linux boxes suffer from this, nor my colleague's Windows machine suffer from this.
- This is specifically about having `PATH` set properly.

What I've tried this far:

- Editing `/etc/paths`: nope, no help.
- Various `~/Library/LaunchAgent` -tips found from the net. Y'know those `launchctl setenv PATH ...`? No help.

Comment: Please don't add a possible answer **in** your question. Instead answer your question by adding  one using *Your answer* - you are expressly encouraged to do so.

Answer (score 1):

After further work on this, I found something that seems to work. I RTM'ed the man page of `launchctl`, and noticed the config-subcommand. So this is what I did:

```
sudo launchctl config user path "paths:I:want:GUI:apps:to:use"
```

Then reboot, as launchctl instructed me to do.

I had added a debug print statement to my gradle file:

```
println System.getenv("PATH")
```

After rebooting, build printed out the changed `PATH` including those parts that I added via `config user path`.